# Sending to external email fail

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Here is the codes:

```
    Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
    Dim mail As New MailMessage()
    Dim attachment As System.Net.Mail.Attachment

    SmtpServer.Credentials = New  _
    Net.NetworkCredential("administrator@company.com", "1234")    
    SmtpServer.Port = 25
    SmtpServer.Host = "SmtpServer"

    mail = New MailMessage()
    mail.From = New MailAddress("user@company.com.my")

    mail.To.Add("recipient@external.com")

    mail.CC.Add("user1@company.com")
    mail.CC.Add("user2@company.com")

    mail.Headers.Add("Disposition-Notification-To", "user1@company.com")   'Read receipt

    mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure    'Fail delivery notification

    mail.Subject = "Sending Documents"

    mail.Body = "To Whom May Concern," & vbCrLf _
    & vbCrLf & "Please refer to the attachment for the documents." & vbCrLf & _
    "NOTE : This is an automatically generated email and will be sent daily."

    For Each path As String In attch
        attachment = New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(path)
        mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)
    Next

    Try
        SmtpServer.Send(mail)
        SmtpServer = Nothing

    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex.ToString)
        Exit Sub

    End Try
```

Problem is only internal email receiving, not external email.
No errors shown during the code execution.
Any idea on how to solve this?
Or do I need to configure something at the Microsoft Exchange Server?
Also the server using the MailMarshal to do the filtering.
An advanced thanks for the contributing feedback.

Comment: Can we assume that you have done the obvious and check both the spam mail / filters and the exchange logs (for thinks like a bounce back, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that "mail.From" value is in the list allowed by SMTP server. It could be that relaying is not allowed.